# How do I append to a Database and add a single object out of the list to a textview?

Tags: android, sql

I want to add items individually every time I hit the add button. Whenever I press the add button, it adds all items twice to the listview.

```
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (task.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter A Task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                String dos = task.getText().toString();
                database.execSQL("create table if not exists tasklist(sub text)");
                database.execSQL("insert into tasklist values('" + dos + "' )");

                Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from tasklist", null);

                while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String name = cursor.getString(0);
                    subject.add(name);
                }
                task.setText("");
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subject);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you post some more code?

Comment: I figured it out. I added this.
             while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        if(cursor.isLast()) {
                            String name = cursor.getString(0);
                            subject.add(name);
                        }
                    }

Comment: Okay, good :) ....